# external paperscript file is not loading at all in my html file

Tags: javascript, html, paperjs

I am trying to make a basic test program for paper.js, which I intend to use for a project.
I am using chrome to run the HTML and when I open the dev tools chrome seems to simply not load one of my scripts. My file structure is:

```
Test
|---mario.svg
|---html.html
|---scripts/
|   |---script.js
|   |---paper-core.js
```

And here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="./scripts/paper-full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" src="./scripts/script.js" canvas="myCanvas"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```
veiw.onFrame = function(event){
    project.importSVG('.../mario.svg');
};
```

In the chrome dev tools however, under sources, I would expect to see something that matches my file structure, and I do, except script.js is missing.
Also it gives me this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/jacob/Documents/JS/Testing/scripts/script.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
ht @ paper-full.min.js:32

I think it must be something to do with the text/paperscript, but I really don't know and definately don't know how to fix it. I've looked at examples and can't figure out what I am doing differently. The mario.svg doesn't show up either but I think that's just because its not referenced in the html. Can someone explain this please?

Comment: Have you tried it without "text/paperscript" type?

Comment: Yes, I have had better luck with it recognising files with just text/javascript. But I need it to be a paperscript

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No. At one point it was giving me an error saying one of them was blocked by CORS, but I can't remember wether it was paper or my script and I can't remember what I did to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, I would say that your PaperScript code is not run because you load the wrong version of Paper.js.
You are loading `paper-core.js` which is the version of Paper.js that does not support PaperScript. You should load `paper-full.js` instead.

Comment: Thanks, good to know, but now it gives me an error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/jacob/Documents/JS/Testing/scripts/script.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
ht @ paper-full.min.js:32
Do you know what origin 'null' means?

Comment: I think that I see what this is about. I guess that you are loading your page by opening your html directly in your browser right ? If so, you will encounter lots of issues like this one, you should use a simple web server instead and load your page accessing its URL. Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server for example.

Comment: @sesensi Thank you so much, I am actually using pythons http.server now but this page finally showed me what url I should be typing into my browser, I've tried with python before but I never knew what to type for the url